# SQL in Access: Complex UPDATE with 3 tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to MS-Access and SQL and finding the syntax a bit confusing to wrap my head around for more complex queries.

Here is a summary of the relevant fields and tables I am working with:

TableA: Master table that I wish to update,contains:

- .barcode - barcode number on asset - correlates to .AssetID in TableB
- .lastseendate - date that the asset was last seen - to be updated

TableB: Linked from external system, record of tested assets, contains:

- .AssetKey - internal index number of the external system
- .AssetID - Scanned barcode number - correlates to .barcode in master table

TableC: Linked from external system, record of individual tests (may contain multiple tests of the item with different dates), contains:

- .Asset (not the table index, not unique in this table) corresponds to the .AssetKey in tableB
- .TestDate

What I am trying to do is update the .lastseendate in my master table using the most recent testdate from tableC and using tableB as a lookup from .barcode to .AssetKey

The query should only update from records that exist in tableB.

Note: Not all records in the master table contain a .barcode - some items are not related to the external system.

If there is a way to do this in Access without SQL that is fine but I expect SQL commands will be the easiest way.

Thanks

Comment: Conventional wisdom is this 'aggregate' calc data should not be saved but calculated when needed. Any UPDATE action SQL involving an aggregate query will fail. If you really must save this data, will require either domain aggregate functions in query or VBA code.

Comment: By 'aggregate' query I mean a query that uses aggregate function like Sum, Max, etc. Domain aggregate functions are DSum, DMax, etc.